# time_t in c for process child

Tags: c, time

I am trying to get the total time a child process has been running, using the following tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_difftime.htm

like that

```
if (process == 0) {
                time(&start_t);
                //..somecode
            } else {
                //wait..
                time(&end_t);
                total_t = difftime(end_t, start_t);
                printf("total: %f\n", total_t);
            }
```

but I am getting weird and sometimes negative results

Thank's for your help

Comment: You need to show how you're waiting and convince me that you spawn a thread not fork. `getrusage` is much better for measuring children though if you're on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing `start_t` in the child process and then trying to read it in the parent where it's still uninitialized (or has a stale value). The correct way to do this is to measure both in the parent, getting the end time after you successfully `waitpid` for the child.